# Function when entered in text box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter for a small Python application. It has a set of ratio buttons, a text box, and a button. Is there a way to make it so the user can simply press Enter/Return on a keyboard and run the same function the button runs? The text box stays selected even when a radio is changed, so that won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to bind an event handler to either the text box widget or the whole application that will be called when the event happens. Assuming you have a function to handle the event, something along the lines of:

```
widget.bind('<Return>', event_handler)
```

You can also bind a handler function at the application level by calling the `bind_all()` method of any widget, e.g.:

```
self.bind_all('<Return>', self.event_handler)
```

Note the key name is `Return` not `Enter`.  See [Key Names](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) for a list of them all. You can also prefix the key name with a modifier like `Shift-` and `Control-` if desired.

There's a decent online reference for tkinter 8.4 [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/).

Comment: I don't think I quite have it... My window is called "app" (`app = Tk()`), and the function I want the Return key to preform is `changeLabel()`. I'm trying `app.bind('<Return>', changeLabel)`, but it keeps giving me `TypeError: changeLabel() takes no arguments (1 given)` when I press return. I tried `app.bind('<Return>', changeLabel())` (changeLabel becomes changeLabel()), but that just gives me an error before the window loads.

Comment: Sorry about the missing `>`. As for the extra argument passed: event handler functions are always passed an event argument. If they're methods they are also passed a `self` parameter as a first argument before the event argument.

Comment: Since I kept getting "takes no arguments (1 given)", I just changed my function from changeLabel() to changeLabel(nil), and return now works, but the actual button if broken because the button gives "takes 1 argument (none given)"

Comment: You need two handlers taking different numbers of arguments because one is attached to a widget and gets a `self` and the other is at the application level and doesn't. One can call the the other. The argument you named `nil` was probably the event argument which you probably is often ignored.

Comment: Kept `changeLabel(nil)` and added `callChangeLabel()`, which does `changeLabel(someUselessVariable)`. Works great, thanks!

Comment: @martineau: you don't necessarily need two handlers. One will suffice if you make the parameter passed by the binding optional (eg: `def event_handler(self, event=None)`) this works great as long as your event handler doesn't depend on that parameter.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: Good point. It's often useful to use default arguments with tkinter's event handler...for this and other common cases. It's even mentioned in the reference manual linked to in one of my earlier comments. I consciously didn't mention it in an effort make things a simple as possible.

Comment: @martineau forgot about that, sorry